# Cannot assign requested address to ssserver config.json

Tags: python, shadow, socks

Setting up shadowsocks and have config.json to my ec2 instance and receiving error 99. Output is as follows:

config file:

```
{
"server":"aws_instance_ip",
"server_port":8023,
"local_address":"127.0.0.1",
"local_port":1080,
"password":"password",
"timeout":300,
"method":"aes-256-cfb:,
"fast_open": false,
"workers": 1,
"prefer_ipv6": false
}
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ssserver", line 11, in <module>
  load_entry_point('shadowsocks==2.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'ssserver')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shadowsocks/server.py", line 74, in main
  tcp_servers.append(tcprelay.TCPRelay(a_config, dns_resolver, False))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shadowsocks/tcprelay.py", line 733, in __init__
  server_socket.bind(sa)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
  return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```